# Am I understanding how a Load Balancer w/ Auto Scale works?

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-platform, haproxy, autoscaling, coreos

I'm wanting to setup a load balancer with auto-scaling for my web app. I'm not sure if I'm understanding the little details on how it works and interacts with my instances.

I'm currently hosting on Google Cloud and am using this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/autoscaled-load-balancing-using-haproxy-and-consul-on-compute-engine#multi-zone_deployment_with_cloud_deployment_manager) as a reference for how to set one up. I'm wanting to use CoreOS as my OS of choice among all my instances.

Below is a diagram in which will help explain my questions better.
[image: lb exmaple]

I understand that the load balancer houses a single IP address as an access point for clients on the internet to access my app. After they've requested the IP, the load balancer figures out which instance to serve them depending on multiple factors such as, network location, HTTP(S) traffic load, etc.

The point that I get confused with is where should my app live? Am I supposed to distribute my app across all of my servers? Is that how it's supposed to be done fundamentally?

I mentioned that I'm using CoreOS. CoreOS has Docker. Would an ideal setup be to Dockerize my app, package it up and have it distributed among my servers so that they can be consistent?

For the auto-scaling part, I plan to have the load balancer distribute traffic to my servers that are within a auto scaling group. In order to have my app present on a newly scaled instance, I will have to include some sort of startup script (cloud-config) in order to have it pull the latest docker image of my app to be able to serve correctly, yes?

Ultimately, I would think having a setup, in the diagram below, would be most ideal for me to learn more and broaden my experience, but also allowing me to make my app as robust and reachable as possible.

[image]

Some questions concerning this are:

For what I want to accomplish, is setting up HAProxy absolutely necessary?

This digram shows that the instances that serve the backend are talking with the load balancer via internal IP'. Are internal IP's required for load balancing in general? Or do they just help secure the content that isn't needed to be made public?

For this diagram, I'm *assuming* an SSL certificate would only need to be loaded on the front-end server that has the external IP, so how would I serve a certificate for a load balancer that doesn't have a means of use for internal IP's?

---

Is thinking that this is complex bad? Is it more simple than what I think?

All and all, I just want to learn and harness these methods so I can make a reliable app that can serve anyone quickly and painlessly without most issues.

If I need to clarify more on anything please let me know and I will do my best to help. If there is anything I should be aware of, please let me know. Most of all, if there any suggestions on a route I should be taking, please do tell!

Any help or feedback is **greatly** appreciated!

Comment: See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TfbEwfYjKl4.

Comment: Already watched this. While it was good, I still had questions that I put in my SO question.

Comment: You had 7 questions, which is a lot for a single post ;-) You will have one copy of your app on each server. Those servers need to be stateless, because they come and go as autoscaling events happen. Persist your data off-instance, in SQL or NoSQL data store. Yes, dynamically bootstrap your instances. However, at some point the image you launch from will be so out of date that bootstrapping will take a long time, so at that point cut a new image and update your autoscaling to use the new image. All machines in GCE have private IPs. Some also have public IPs. Yes, SSL cert on the LB.